# How to connect to AWS service from local IDE(PyCharm) using IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I want a run a python boto3 scrip from my local machine using Pycharm. I am having config file setup in my machine that contains different roles based on the accounts. Say for example I want to execute the scrip using dev-power user that is included in the config file. But I am getting the below error:
"botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"

Could you please let me know the process by which I can do this from local IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use IAM Role to access AWS services from your development environment. An IAM Role can only be attached to an IAM User or an AWS service and cannot be used for programmatic access.

For programmatic access to different AWS services you will need to create an IAM User which will have access to required services or has a role attached to it with specific policies.

Reference :

[AWS IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

[AWS IAM Users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html)

IAM User provides "access-key" and "secrete-key" which can be configured on your machine to access the services from your development environment.

Reference :

[AWS Access Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)

[Setting up your AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail explanation. I spun up an EC2 instance and  running the script.

Comment: @Prantik Pariksha That&#39;s great. Though it would be better to use the access credentials for development purpose.